# How to import system tables, stored procs and views

Tags: database-schema, sql-server-data-tools

In VS 2010, when importing master db, all system tables, views and stored procedures cannot be imported into my project. There are no scripts under Tables, Views and StoredProcedure folders.

For custom db, the scripts can be generated properly.

How can I make the scripts for system object generate for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to import master.dbschema as a reference into your project.

See the following http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386242.aspx